# I bonds interest calculation

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds

Current I bond annualized rate is 6.89%. How much interest will accrue in the next 6 months on a $10,000 purchase. Note 6.89% is not what will be earned in a year since the next 6 months will have a different CPI-U.

Answer (score 3):

In 6 months you'd accrue half of the annual interest rate, or 3.445%, or $344.50 on a $10,000 I-bond.  After that 6 months, the accrued interest is added to the principal value of the bond, and is used to calculate the *next* 6 months of interest, so the interest compounds semi-annually.